# NSArrayController binding to One-To-Many relationship in a NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

I'm working on an application using Core Data. My model is basically a list of objects, which are called "Descriptions". Each description has a list of "Properties". This is a really simple one-to-many relationship. I have a NSTableView who contains 2 columns.

I'm using binding to fill my table view with the list of my properties :

```
self.controller = [[NSArrayController alloc] initWithContent: self.descriptionObject.properties];

NSTableColumn *propertyColumn = [self.propertiesTableView tableColumnWithIdentifier: @"property_column"];
[propertyColumn bind: NSValueBinding toObject: self.controller withKeyPath: @"arrangedObjects.name" options: nil];

NSTableColumn *infoColumn = [self.propertiesTableView tableColumnWithIdentifier: @"info_column"];
[infoColumn bind: NSValueBinding toObject: self.controller withKeyPath: @"arrangedObjects.info" options: nil];
```

I have a button that calls my "addProperty" method :

```
- (IBAction)addProperty:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Add a new property");

    PCSDescriptionProperty *property = [PCSDescriptionProperty insertInManagedObjectContext: self.storage.managedObjectContext];
    property.name = @"New property";
    property.info = @"New property info";

    [self.descriptionObject addPropertiesObject: property];
}
```

The problem is, calling `addPropertiesObject:` does not trigger a KVO notification and my tableview is not refreshed. I've tried calling willChangeValueForKey/didChangeValueForKey before and after with addPropertiesObject without success.

Any idea why ? 
Thanks !

Comment: Try setting the property.description = self.descriptionObject rather than adding the property to the description object.  Also make sure you have correctly set up both relationships correctly.  And I would set the ArrayController entity to @"Property", its managedObjectContext to the managedObjectContext and its contentSet to description.properties.  That would be how you do it in IB.

Comment: Actually the relationship works because I can see the changes being saved, it really it the NSArrayController's content that is not "re-fetched".

Comment: you should still bind the contextSet to descriptionObject.properties for To-Many relationships.  Don't use initWithContent.

Comment: This is what I added then : 

    self.controller = [[NSArrayController alloc] init];
    [self.controller bind: NSContentSetBinding toObject: self.descriptionObject withKeyPath: @"properties" options: nil];

Now it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Duncan Groenewald, here what I did : I stopped using initWithContent: and actually bound my set of properties to the NSContentSet of my ArrayController :

```
self.controller = [[NSArrayController alloc] init];
[self.controller bind: NSContentSetBinding toObject: self.apiDescription withKeyPath: @"properties" options: nil];
```

Then, in my addProperty: method, all I add to do was to reverse the way I added my new property to my description one :

```
property.descriptionObject = self.descriptionObject;
```

Answer (score 2):

The table View will not be refreshed once drawn. You need to explicitly call `reloadData` on your table view. `[yourTableView reloadData];` after setting the property.

Another way of doing the same thing is: After adding the properties to description, also add property to the arrayController. `[self.controller addObject:property];` It will append the object to the tableView and no refresh is required.

If nothing works, (not a recommended approach) reset the content of the tableView.

```
[self.controller setContent:self.descriptionObject.properties];
```

Comment: So there is now way to automatically trigger the NSTableView refresh  ? I'm pretty sure I managed to to it once, when I was using a NS(Mutable)Array as a content to my array controller. I'll try to add the object to my collection as well but.. meh.

Comment: You need to reload the data for NSTableView if you are adding to the array object only. NSArrayController will take care of that part internally.

Comment: Not really now that I use binding, but +1 for answer :)